# installing mechanize on a mac with an error

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, rubygems

I have tried to install mechanize on my Mac but I always get error. I tried all answers given on the site but none worked for me.

I have tried sudo gem install mechanize and I got error below.

```
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mechanize:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160703-8312-16oc548.rb extconf.rb
Using pkg-config version 1.1.7
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4.

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin15/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin15/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
    unsigned short* in = (unsigned short*) inb;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:815:27: warning: cast from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Wcast-align]
    unsigned short* out = (unsigned short*) outb;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
  CC       error.lo
  CC       parserInternals.lo
  CC       parser.lo
  CC       tree.lo
  CC       hash.lo
  CC       list.lo
  CC       xmlIO.lo
xmlIO.c:1450:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_OK'
    ret =  (__libxml2_xzclose((xzFile) context) == LZMA_OK ) ? 0 : -1;
                                                   ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [xmlIO.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `chdir'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in `compile'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:364:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:363:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:555:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out
```

I have install Xcode command line and when I do this

```
xcode-select -p
```

I get /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

this is also the error when I try nokogiri
Admins-MBP:~ admin$ sudo gem install nokogiri

```
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160703-27126-1ef91wn.rb extconf.rb
Using pkg-config version 1.1.7
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4.

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin15/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin15/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
      _xmlIconvWrapper in libxml2.a(encoding.o)
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
      _xmlFindCharEncodingHandler in libxml2.a(encoding.o)
      _xmlCharEncCloseFunc in libxml2.a(encoding.o)
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      _xmlFindCharEncodingHandler in libxml2.a(encoding.o)
  "_lzma_auto_decoder", referenced from:
      _xz_head in libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
  "_lzma_code", referenced from:
      _xz_decomp in libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
  "_lzma_end", referenced from:
      ___libxml2_xzclose in libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
  "_lzma_properties_decode", referenced from:
      _is_format_lzma in libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [xmllint] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `chdir'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in `compile'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:364:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:363:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:555:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out
```

When I use 
Admins-MBP:~ admin$ sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.7.2'

```
Password:
Fetching: mini_portile2-2.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile2-2.0.0
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.7.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/ext/nokogiri
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160703-32388-1almq9.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.0.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
    - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch
    - 0003-Stop-parsing-on-entities-boundaries-errors.patch
    - 0004-Cleanup-conditional-section-error-handling.patch
    - 0005-CVE-2015-1819-Enforce-the-reader-to-run-in-constant-.patch
    - 0006-Another-variation-of-overflow-in-Conditional-section.patch
    - 0007-Fix-an-error-in-previous-Conditional-section-patch.patch
    - 0008-CVE-2015-8035-Fix-XZ-compression-support-loop.patch
    - 0009-Updated-config.guess.patch
    - 0010-Fix-parsering-short-unclosed-comment-uninitialized-access.patch
    - 0011-Avoid-extra-processing-of-MarkupDecl-when-EOF.patch
    - 0012-Avoid-processing-entities-after-encoding-conversion-.patch
    - 0013-CVE-2015-7497-Avoid-an-heap-buffer-overflow-in-xmlDi.patch
    - 0014-CVE-2015-5312-Another-entity-expansion-issue.patch
    - 0015-Add-xmlHaltParser-to-stop-the-parser.patch
    - 0016-Detect-incoherency-on-GROW.patch
    - 0017-CVE-2015-7500-Fix-memory-access-error-due-to-incorre.patch
    - 0018-CVE-2015-8242-Buffer-overead-with-HTML-parser-in-pus.patch
    - 0019-Do-not-print-error-context-when-there-is-none.patch
    - 0020-xmlStopParser-reset-errNo.patch
    - 0021-Reuse-xmlHaltParser-where-it-makes-sense.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin15/ports/libxml2/2.9.2... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0003-Stop-parsing-on-entities-boundaries-errors.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0004-Cleanup-conditional-section-error-handling.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0005-CVE-2015-1819-Enforce-the-reader-to-run-in-constant-.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0006-Another-variation-of-overflow-in-Conditional-section.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0007-Fix-an-error-in-previous-Conditional-section-patch.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0008-CVE-2015-8035-Fix-XZ-compression-support-loop.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0009-Updated-config.guess.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0010-Fix-parsering-short-unclosed-comment-uninitialized-access.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0011-Avoid-extra-processing-of-MarkupDecl-when-EOF.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0012-Avoid-processing-entities-after-encoding-conversion-.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0013-CVE-2015-7497-Avoid-an-heap-buffer-overflow-in-xmlDi.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0014-CVE-2015-5312-Another-entity-expansion-issue.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0015-Add-xmlHaltParser-to-stop-the-parser.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0016-Detect-incoherency-on-GROW.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0017-CVE-2015-7500-Fix-memory-access-error-due-to-incorre.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0018-CVE-2015-8242-Buffer-overead-with-HTML-parser-in-pus.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0019-Do-not-print-error-context-when-there-is-none.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0020-xmlStopParser-reset-errNo.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/patches/libxml2/0021-Reuse-xmlHaltParser-where-it-makes-sense.patch... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.2... ERROR, review '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin15/ports/libxml2/2.9.2/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
  "_gzwrite", referenced from:
      _xmlGzfileWrite in libxml2.a(xmlIO.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      _xmlNanoHTTPRead in libxml2.a(nanohttp.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      _xmlNanoHTTPFreeCtxt in libxml2.a(nanohttp.o)
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      _xmlNanoHTTPScanAnswer in libxml2.a(nanohttp.o)
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
      _xmlIconvWrapper in libxml2.a(encoding.o)
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
      _xmlFindCharEncodingHandler in libxml2.a(encoding.o)
      _xmlCharEncCloseFunc in libxml2.a(encoding.o)
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      _xmlFindCharEncodingHandler in libxml2.a(encoding.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [xmllint] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.0.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.0.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `chdir'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.0.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.0.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in `compile'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.0.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:289:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:182:in `block in chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:181:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:181:in `chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:288:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:187:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:187:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:478:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/gem_make.out
```

another error

```
Admins-MBP:~ admin$ sudo gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libxslt --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/opt/libiconv --with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/opt/libxml2 --with-xml2-config=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin/xml2-config --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2 --with-xslt-config=/usr/local/opt/libxslt/bin/xslt-config
Password:
Building native extensions with: '--use-system-libraries --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libxslt --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/opt/libiconv --with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/opt/libxml2 --with-xml2-config=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin/xml2-config --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2 --with-xslt-config=/usr/local/opt/libxslt/bin/xslt-config'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160703-514-1ycei3y.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libxslt --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/opt/libiconv --with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/opt/libxml2 --with-xml2-config=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin/xml2-config --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2 --with-xslt-config=/usr/local/opt/libxslt/bin/xslt-config
Using pkg-config version 1.1.7
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
checking for libexslt... no
ERROR: cannot discover where libxml2 is located on your system. please make sure `pkg-config` is installed.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-exslt-dir
    --without-exslt-dir
    --with-exslt-include
    --without-exslt-include=${exslt-dir}/include
    --with-exslt-lib
    --without-exslt-lib=${exslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libexslt-config
    --without-libexslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-override-variables
    --without-override-variables

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Would you mind to also show the error log of `gem install nokogiri`?

Comment: @Harsh Trivedi I added it above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same issue. Consider installing **rbenv** https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv which makes it easy to switch between installed versions of Ruby. With rbenv you can download/install almost any version of Ruby and then install the mechanize Gem.

—OR—

Run this command for CL tools:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

You will be prompted to install tools or receive this error:

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

The run these commands to install the Gem (use sudo at your own discretion):

```
gem update --system
gem uninstall nokogiri
echo "gem: -n/usr/local/bin" >> ~/.gemrc
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
sudo gem install nokogiri -n/usr/local/bin -v '1.6.3.1' -- --with-opt-include=$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include
sudo gem install mechanize
```

Mechanize requires minimum version 1.6, so Nokogiri 1.6.3.1 will work: https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize.gemspec#L56

---

For further issues see:

- http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html
- https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues
- https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/issues

Comment: I am getting error with your solution , please look at above

Comment: I get error for the three brew commands you gave.   Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2

Comment: I used your solution and I got another error. Please look at above!!! It seems like it does not want to be installed :((

Comment: @SoAwesomeMan,  *It seems you're using the libxml2 that comes with nokogiri and that's what the problem is*--Huh?  Nokogiri is now a self contained gem that no longer depends on libxml2 being installed on your system.  The error message: *ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.* is the typical non-sensical error message that in my experience means: "Hey, you don't know what you are doing, and I don't either. You are not even close, so STOP.  Try something else."

Comment: @7stud, ok. I meant _comes with nokogiri as a vendored version at gnome and downloaded upon install vs. /usr/local/opt/libxml2_

Comment: The same happened to me after xcode was updated to 8.1. I ran xcode-install several times but each time it started downloading the tools again. Finally, it turns out that I needed to open xcode for the first time after upgrade, which also installs the required tools.

Comment: I faced the same problem. I tried your method but it didn't work. Then I tried to do: `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include/libxml2:$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include/libxml2/libxml:$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include` after `xcode-select --install` succeed. And then `gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries`, and the installation is successful. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried sudo...

1) To verify downloads, install [gpgTools](https://gpgtools.org).

2) Install [rvm](https://rvm.io) (Ruby Version Manager):

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

2) Use rvm to install your own copy of ruby (**DO NOT USE SUDO**):

```
$ rvm install 2.3.1
```

3) Install all the gems you want into your copy of ruby--error free (**DO NOT USE SUDO**):

```
$ gem install mechanize
```

If you ever use `sudo` when issuing any of the commands above, chop off one of your fingers.  By the time you finish with one hand, you'll get the hang of it.

Comment: why should I use sudo? I liked your answer but the above answer solved my problem so I don't know if yours also could get me somewhere. however, I appreciate your time,

Comment: bring your hand I want to chop your arm OFF :-D, Admins-MBP:~ admin$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
-bash: gpg: command not found